# BitMap Indexes vs Btree Indexes evaluation affected by order of queries run?

Tags: sql, oracle, bitmap, b-tree

I am trying to evaluate BitMap indexes performance over Btree indexes.In my efforts I found out that the time taken for running the queries differs when I change the order which I run the queries.
For example when running two queries

> **Query 1**- Run against one Fact  and dimension set(Star Schema) solely
>   containing  bitMap Indexes.
>
> **Query 2** - Run against one fact and dimension set (Star Scehma)solely
>   containing Btree indexes.

--

> Day1:- I ran **Query 1** and the time taken was 47.53 secs.
>          I ran **Query 2** and the time taken was 34.08 secs
>
> Day 2 :- flushed the buffer cache
>          I ran **Query 2** first and the time taken was 32.66 secs
>          I ran **Query 1** and the time taken was 12.11 secs

Both the queries follow the same join path and only differ in the table names depending upon the index on the table. If the `table A` is Btree indexed table then `Table Abx` is bitmap indexed table.

My question is whether the order in which these queries are run affected the timing of these queries? what would have caused this kind of behavior in Oracle?

Comment: What happens if you run Query 1 twice and then Query 2 twice? Each second run should take full advantage of data being cached.

Comment: Yes..Both the queries ran faster..query1 took 1.13 seconds and query2 took 1.10 secs

Comment: There is a huge difference between cached and non-cached timing. I'd suspect Query 1 can better reuse cache state after Query 2 than the other way around.

Comment: But shouldn't  that be true only for consecutive runs rather than running them a day apart?by which I mean allowing any kind of cache to be cleared?

Comment: It all depends on what kind of activity you have in your database during the day. If your tables and indices are being used during the day - good chance they would be in the cache.

Comment: so would the explanation here be that the first query is better cached than the second?

Comment: Query 1 can better reuse cache state left after Query 2 than the other way around.

Comment: I was under the assumption that flushing the buffer cache would have avoided this behavior? was that assumption not accurate?

Comment: Correct. Both flushing the buffer and running the query twice should produce consistent and reproducible result, that might have very little if any meaning for real - life situation where cache state is always changing.